# How to convert an array to object in JsonConverter

Tags: .net, json.net, serialization

I want to change a type of a property from array to object by using a `JsonConverter`. For example, I have a property like this `[{"Name":"aaa"}]`.  After serializing I want to have the result like this `{"__po":"Add",Objects:[{"Name":"aaa"}]}`.

So I created a class for customizing my serializer:

```
public class Serializer : ISerializer
{
    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }

    public Serializer()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ParseArrayToObjectJsonConverter());
    }

    public class ParseArrayToObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            if (objectType.GetTypeInfo().Name.EndsWith("Array"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I see that `JsonWriter` has this property `public WriteState WriteState { get; }` which can return an enum like this: `public enum WriteState { Error = 0, Closed = 1, Object = 2, Array = 3, Constructor = 4, Property = 5, Start = 6 }`.

In my the `WriteJson` method, the type of `writer.WriteState` is `WriteState.Array`, but the problem is I can't set the value of `WriteState` for returning an object.  Do you have any other solutions for handling this problem?

Comment: JsonWriter have this property  public WriteState WriteState { get; } who can return an enum like this  'public enum WriteState
    {
        Error = 0,
        Closed = 1,
        Object = 2,
        Array = 3,
        Constructor = 4,
        Property = 5,
        Start = 6
    }' in my case the value of Writer.WriteState is WriteState.Array  but the problem i can't set the value of Writer.WriteState for returning an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how to use the `JsonWriter` within a `JsonConverter`.  You should never need to mess with the writer's `WriteState`.   It is a read-only property that indicates what the writer is currently writing.  You cannot change it directly.  Instead, you should be using the writer's `WriteXxx()` methods to actually write out the JSON you want.  Here is how you would implement a `JsonConverter` that wraps an array in an object:

```
public class WrapArrayInObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // This will cause the converter to wrap ALL IEnumerables (except strings) in an object.
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && objectType != typeof(string);

        // If you only want to this converter to wrap specific kinds of arrays, change this
        // method accordingly.  For example, this will only wrap Foo[] or List<Foo>:
        //return typeof(IEnumerable<Foo>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable array = (IEnumerable)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("__po");
        writer.WriteValue("Add");
        writer.WritePropertyName("Objects");
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (object item in array)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using the converter:

```
Foo[] array = new Foo[]
{
    new Foo { Name = "aaa" },
    new Foo { Name = "bbb" }
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new WrapArrayInObjectJsonConverter());

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"__po":"Add","Objects":[{"Name":"aaa"},{"Name":"bbb"}]}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/79mXF2

Comment: This is Exactly what I need Thank you very mush Mr. @Brian :)